# Number Theory, Perfect square number problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Q. n is perfect square number. n's tens digit is not 0 and n's units digit is not 0.

If remove n's tens digit and units digit, remain number is still perfect square number.

Find maximum of n.

(My English skill is bad... Sorry..)

I want to solve this problem.

Maybe I think If n is 916, n is satisfied that condition. But not the maximum.

But how to I think properly to solve this problem?

I tried this too, n=k^2, k^2=a_1 a_2 a_3 ... a_n, a_1 a_2 a_3 ... a_n-3 a_n-2 = m^2

And I don't know what to do...

Please give me some hint.

Answer (score 2):

First, $916$ is not a square number, I guess you mean $961$.

In your notation,

$$(a_1a_2\ldots a_{l-2}a_{l-1}a_{l})_{10}=n=k^2, (a_1a_2\ldots a_{l-2})_{10}=m^2, $$

where $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ are the decimal digits of $n$ and the $(x\ldots y)_{10}$ notation means the number formed of the digits  $x\ldots y$ in base $10$.

Note that,

$$(a_1a_2\ldots a_{l-2}00)_{10}=100m^2 = (10m)^2$$

so $n=k^2 \ge (10m)^2$. Since $a_l,a_{l-1} \neq 0$, we actually have $n=k^2 > (10m)^2$. Now consider that the next square number after $(10m)^2$ is $(10m+1)^2$, which equals $100m^2+20m+1$.

With

$$(a_1a_2\ldots a_{l-2}a_{l-1}a_{l})_{10}=n=k^2 \le (a_1a_2\ldots a_{l-2}00)_{10} + 99 = 100m^2+99,$$

can you continue?

Comment: Wow!! That is awsome!! Thank you, i will try and back!! If I have trouble ask again with comment.

Comment: Yes!! I solve this problem. The answer is 1681 right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Matholic Correct! This method of trying to find a square number that is just a little bit smaller than a a "supposed to be" square number and then using the fact that square numbers have a certain distance between each other is often useful.